# Regex: Trying to match a prefix anywhere in a string multiple times

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex for my C# app and having trouble getting the matches I'm looking for...

The jist of the problem is that I'm trying to pick out strings that need to be translated and replace them with their internationalized counterpart. The regex is for picking out the translatable resources. We've decided to prefix all translatable resources with "OH_" Putting them back to back seems the be the issue with the regex. Do I need to state that they must be separated by a space at a minimum?

```
OH_OrderItemStatusChanged
Style1PS1A1OH_OrderItemStatusSpacerOH_OrderItemStatusID_2
(OH_OrderItemSentTo )  (OH_SalesRep )
```

My Regex is `OH_\w+`

It finds the following matches:

```
OH_OrderItemStatusChanged
OH_OrderItemStatusSpacerOH_OrderItemStatusID_2
OH_OrderItemSentTo
OH_SalesRep
```

The second match should actually be two matches:

```
OH_OrderItemStatusSpacer
OH_OrderItemStatusID_2
```

I've looked at several examples and can't find what i'm looking for. Is this something that can be done in a regex, or do I have to break it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OH_\w+
```

is a good start, but of course `\w+` also matches `OH_`, so you need to exclude that from the match. This requires the use of a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
OH_(?:(?!OH_)\w)+
```

**Explanation:**

```
OH_       # Match OH_.
(?:       # Start of non-capturing group:
 (?!OH_)  # Assert that we're not at the start of the string OH_,
 \w       # then match an alnum character.
)+        # Repeat as often as possible.
```

See it [on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yZ3nI7).

Comment: That works. Have to wait a few more minutes to accept this answer. I'll experiment with this more to better understand it, but sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: I had tried the (?!OH_), but didn't think to include the \w with it in a group. That was the magic that I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

*Tim Pietzcker*'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846411/1715579) is excellent, but here's an alternative:

```
(OH_\w+?)+\b
```

This will match `OH_` followed by one or more word characters, non-greedily. And it will allow that group to be captured one or more times before the end of the string. This means you'll have to inspect the `Captures` collection to get all the results. For example:

```
var input = "OH_OrderItemStatusSpacerOH_OrderItemStatusID_2";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(OH_\w+?)+\b");
foreach(Capture c in matches[0].Groups[1].Captures)
    Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
```

This will produce:

> OH_OrderItemStatusSpacer
>
> OH_OrderItemStatusID_2

Comment: Nice alternate solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex...

```
OH_.*?(?=(OH_|\r|\)))
```